# How to download multiple files without zip in java?

Tags: java, servlets, download

**How to download multiple files (.txt or .ep) in java ?( using multiple pop-up downloading windows provides by browser )**

The process is like this
 1. select the files using check box,
2. click Download Button
3. display multiple pop-up windows for downloading selected files

**The actual problem is that when I selected 3 files ,only first file can be download .**

```
<select name="foldname" id="test-select">
```

The servelet code is below

```
String[] fdnam=request.getParameterValues("foldname");
        if(select.length!=1)
        {
            for(String select1 : select)                                   
            {
                if(fdnam!=null){  
                String[] lm=select1.split("/");
                String realPath=dbHandlerObj.getbasepath(lm[0],lm[1]);
                select1=realPath+File.separator+select1;

                }
                filenames.add(new File(select1));                            
            }
            for (int i=0; i<filenames.size(); i++) {
             int BUFSIZE =4096;

             int length   = 0;

             File file = new File(filenames.get(i).toString());
             System.out.println("File1["+i+"]="+file);
             System.out.println("FileLength["+i+"]="+file.length());

             String LastName=file.getName();

             response.setContentLength((int)file.length());
             response.setContentType("text/html");
             response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + LastName + "\"");

             byte[] byteBuffer= new byte [BUFSIZE];

             ServletOutputStream outS= response.getOutputStream();
             DataInputStream in=new DataInputStream(new FileInputStream (file));  


             while ((in != null) && ((length = in.read(byteBuffer)) != -1))

                {
                    outS.write(byteBuffer,0,length);
                }
             in.close();
             outS.flush();
             outS.close();

            } 
         }
```

**I need to download the selected files in multiple pop up boxes**

Comment: What is `select` in servlet code and are you getting any error ?

Comment: @SudhirOjha `select` is String array and will get the memory locations of the selected files like {C:/Users/ipc/Downloads/new.txt,C:/Users/ipc/Downloads/new.ep,C:/Users/ipc/Downloads/time.txt} and there is no error. But can download only 1 file.

Comment: **No answers..?**